# I keep getting Json decodeerror every time I use woocommerce python API

Tags: python, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to get the json data of my woocommerce product list with python but I keep getting errors despite supplying the necessary details. If I try to get the text format, it returns the html correctly.

```
from woocommerce import API
wcapi = API(url='http://localhost/mysite/index.php/product/pizza/',
        consumer_key="ck_xxxxxxxxxxx",
        consumer_secret="cs_xxxxxxxxx", 
        version="wc/v3")
get_product=wcapi.get("products").json()
print(get_product)
```

The Error:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-d30acb9b03bb> in <module>
  4             consumer_secret="cs_ee6fbd92294f88051d8e1a5a2c0201ab1a0f6aff",
  5             version="wc/v3")
----> 6 get_product=wcapi.get("products").json()
  7 print(get_product)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
973             # Catch JSON-related errors and raise as requests.JSONDecodeError
974             # This aliases json.JSONDecodeError and simplejson.JSONDecodeError
--> 975             raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
976 
977     @property

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: What is the raw response text ? wcapi.get("products").text()

Comment: It returned the html code of the page and when I checked the status code, it returned 200

Comment: You can't use that API with `HTTP` use need `HTTPS` or you'll have to use the `HTTP` auth method that is described in woocommerce docs.